# Could not connect to the database. (pyodbc.Error) [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login failed for user '%user%'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

We've migrated our SQL server from version 2012 to 2017, and now we can't connect to the database.

```
(pyodbc.Error) ('28000', "[28000]
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user
'usintranet'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Does anyone have the same issue?

We use python36 and python3.

The paremeters for the code below are:

```
name: 'producao:integracao18'
type: 'mssql'
conf:
  user: 'userlist'
  password: 'password2019'
  host: '176.1.1.1'
  port: 134
  database: 'CRM'
```

The method for connecting to the database is:

```
def connect(self, driver, conf):
    """Connects to a database and returns the connection instance"""
    conn = None

    # see http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html
    if driver == 'sqlite':
        conn = f"sqlite:///{conf['local']}"
    elif driver == 'mysql':
        conn = f"mysql://{conf['usuario']}:{conf['senha']}@{conf['host']}:{conf['porta']}/{conf['database']}"
    elif driver == 'mssql':
        conn = f"mssql+pyodbc://{conf['usuario']}:{conf['senha']}@{conf['host']}:{conf['porta']}/{conf['database']}"
        # MSSQL needs pyodbc and a specific driver, you can check the available ones with pyodbc.drivers()
        conn += '?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server'
```

Comment: Did you use a similar connection with MSSQL 2012 including with f strings and config file? Please show working connection if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't encountered this error, but the first thing I'd verify is that your ODBC settings are still properly configured on your host computer.

I'm not familiar with pyodbc, but if the tip above doesn't help, you should verify that your version of pyodbc is compatible with the ODBC driver you're using.